# Declaring a for loop function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a for loop that searches for a value in an array in my javascript code in couchDb. I want to make it into a function. This should be fairly simple but I am having trouble with it. This is the for loop(Which works perfectly fine):

```
if (newDoc.destination && newDoc.destination.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < newDoc.destination.length; i++) {
        if (newDoc.destination[i].address) return;
    }
}
throw({forbidden: 'doc.address is required'});
```

And this is the way I wrapped it into a function:

```
function arrayReq(field, message) {
    message = message || "Array must have a " + field;
    if (newDoc.destination && newDoc.destination.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < newDoc.destination.length; i++) {
            if (newDoc.destination[i].field) return;
        }
    }
    throw({forbidden: message});
}
```

I would think that the return in the function should stop the function from going any further but it still throws the error. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Btw if i change field into address it works fine. Can I not make the address into a changeable variable?

Comment: *"I would think that the return in the function should stop the function from going any further but it still throws the error. "* It does. If `newDoc.destination[i].field` is ever truthy, that function will not reach the `throw` at the end. So the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Note: `throw` is not a function, there's no need to wrap its operand in `()`. It *is* usually best to throw instances of `Error`, though, although you can throw any object you like.

Comment: Should be closed as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable.

Comment: What did you find when you walked through the code with the debugger? I assume you stopped on the second line with the `if` statement, and then examined the value of `newDoc.destination[i].field`, and then what did you find? Did that help you track down the source of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to use `field` as both a string variable, and a property of your object inside the `destination[]` array.

In your code, if the `destination[i]` object does not have a property called `field` (not the string value populated in the `field` parameter, but an actual property named "field") it will never  evaluate to true and break out of the function.

To access a property of an object by using the string representation in javascript, you use the indexer syntax.

Try changing it from `array.destination[i].field` to `array.destination[i][field]`

Comment: Ohh I see. Thank you so much. I'm fairly new to javascript.